# Database provider with API

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am programming an android app, which needs a Database. My app works like a chat program, so that one user is sending a message to the Database (this message contains two strings in general) and another user should get a notification and access to the message the first user sent to the database.

Because it is not that clever to 'hardcode' the login data for the database in the app, I need something like PHP to get the requested data for example with JSON from the database. Are there any free or < 20$/month web services which offer this (MySQL Server and a API to let android/java connect to it and an authentication system with email/password or facebook)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try: http://buddy.com/

Buddy has a free service:

> **Unlimited** API calls (20/sec rate cap)
>
> Up to **10GB** of storage per app Up
>
> to **5MM** push notifications
>
> Choose your backend location: **US** or **EU**

If you want to use PHP you can use a free hosting or buy one.

> http://www.hostgator.com (premium, PHP Ruby Python)
>
> http://www.000webhost.com (free)
>
> http://www.1freehosting.com (free)

These are just examples, if you want to be sure, you should spend some time on google to find the best for you !!

Good luck!

Comment: I already tried 000webhost.com and some other sites but I wasn't that convinced. Buddy seems to be a good start, I'll try it. Thanks for your fast answer!